# テーブルのアコーディオン表示について

Tags: javascript, html

#### 実現したいこと

HTML、javascripyを使用してテーブルのアコーディオン表示を綺麗に表示したい

#### 試したこと

パターン1：同じテーブル内にdetailの情報を追加
https://codepen.io/st410gaku/pen/xxmEeRB
パターン2：trにtd,tableを追加し、detailの情報を追加
https://codepen.io/st410gaku/pen/JjwRzdO
※カテゴリ1,カテゴリ2を押下するとdetail情報が表示されます。

#### 困っていること

- 可能であればパターン1の方法でアコーディオン表示をしたいのですが、
  『カテゴリ1』押下した際detailのカテゴリ1-1,カテゴリ1-2,カテゴリ1-3の全てを表示する方法がわからない
  （現在のところ、カテゴリ1-1のみ非表示が解除できる状態）
- 調べてパターン2の方法を試してみましたが、detailの1-1,1-2,1-3は表示できますが、
  今度はdetailのテーブルを入れているtr>tdが見えて綺麗に表示できない
  （できればパターン1のように親と子のテーブルを1つの表として表示できればいいのですが…）

※データについては固定

どのように改善していいか検討もつかず困っています... どうかよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: できるだけ質問が自己完結するように、コードは外部サイトに掲載するのでなく、質問に直接記載して下さい。
現在のリンク先のコードは[再現可能な短いサンプルコードの書き方](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)に沿っていそうですし、そのままで良いと思います。
なお、このサイトにもCodePenのような機能の「JavaScript/HTML/CSSスニペット」が有り、編集エリアの上部のボタンで挿入できますが、使い方が解らない場合は、ただコードを貼り付けるので構いません。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 『カテゴリ1』押下した際detailのカテゴリ1-1,カテゴリ1-2,カテゴリ1-3の全てを表示する方法がわからない

現在のコードでは

```js
const classRow = button.parentElement.nextElementSibling;
classRow.classList.toggle("accordion-content");
```

このようにボタンの次の一行だけの表示状態を切り替えています。これを、「サブカテゴリが続く限り行の表示状態を切り替える」というコードに変更する必要があります。
「サブカテゴリである」は「`.accordion-button`を含まない」で判定できるかと思います。

```js
let classRow = ...;
while (classRow && !classRow.querySelector(".accordion-button")) {
  classRow.classList.toggle("accordion-content");
  classRow = classRow.nextElementSibling;
}
```